# Initializing Realm Object class with multiple required initilizers

Tags: swift, realm

I am initializing Realm object and I am getting these errors when I try to initialize the class:
[image]
After I add the initializer for realm, the errors are still there. Is this a bug with xcode?

Looking at the sample code for swift-realm ios project [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift/Simple/AppDelegate.swift), it looks like I don't need to call the required realm. Maybe the sample code is outdated.

EDIT ---
Here's a paste of the code:

```
class AgencyR: Object {
    @objc dynamic var agency_id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var agency_name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var agency_timezone: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var agency_url: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var agency_lang: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var agency_phone: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var agency_fare_url: String = ""

    required init(realm:Realm, agency_id: String, agency_name: String, agency_timezone: String, agency_url: String, agency_lang: String, agency_phone: String, agency_fare_url: String) {
        self.init()
        self.agency_id = agency_id
        self.agency_name = agency_name
        self.agency_timezone = agency_timezone
        self.agency_url = agency_url
        self.agency_lang = agency_lang
        self.agency_phone = agency_phone
        self.agency_fare_url = agency_fare_url
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return self.agency_id
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't include code as screenshot in a question. Include it as text using proper formatting along with the error messages also included as text and pointing out which line of code produces said error messages.

Comment: Don't include code as screenshot in a question, Add your code :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to create a designated initializer for an `Object` subclass, you'd need to implement all required initializers of `Object` since the compiler will not be able to synthetise those for you anymore.

You can get around this issue by making your custom initializer a convenience initializer rather than a designated one, which will allow you to call a designated initializer of the class rather than having to call the superclass initializer. You can still mark the convenience initializer as required.

You also have an issue in your `primaryKey` function. Since the function is a type function, you don't have access to the instance from inside the function, so you cannot call `self` to access an instance property. However, there's no need to do that anyways, since you simply need to return the variable name as a `String` that you want to use as a primary key.

```
class A: Object {
    @objc dynamic var a = 1

    required convenience init(_ a:Int) {
        self.init()
        self.a = a
    }

    override static func primaryKey()->String?{
        return "a"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this resolved my issue. Swift is very new to me and this is something that is not easy to find in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `-> Object`, instead of `->String?` as agency_id is of type Object.Try this.